# How to get user meta by user ID in a custom Gutenberg block

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

As the title says, I just need to get user meta by the user ID in a custom Gutenberg block (editor side). Essentially what this would return in PHP: `get_user_meta( $user_id, 'meta_key', true );` is the data that I need.

`wp.data.select('core').getUserMeta(userId,'meta_key',true);` doesn't seem to work, but it was a total guess as I can't seem to find any documentation about it. Does anyone know how I can do this?

UPDATE:
I figured out a workaround and [posted it here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/412855/how-to-get-user-meta-by-id-in-custom-gutenberg-block) but if anyone knows the right way to do this, please still post your answer!

Comment: Since gutenberg generally is static content, it may not be the best Idea to do this with JS, but a Gutenberg PHP function. I may be wrong, since I don't know your usecase.

Comment: Thanks @Frizzant - can you clarify this or give me a lead on what I should research? It's a dynamic block so I've got the frontend working fine, but I wasn't aware PHP functions could be used on the edit side of Gutenberg.

Comment: Well they can't be. I was not sure if you were using a dynamic block, so I assumed you are not, since I feel most people don't know that they exist. In that case I would have to do quite some research myself, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Your `useSelect(select => select('core').getUsers());` approach as [outlined here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/412867/194155) works and is very neat. I had a similiar requirement and found a different way to get custom user meta that was already registered in the Users REST API. It may not be a better approach, just a different approach using `apiFetch`:

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from '@wordpress/element';

/**
* @param id User id
* @param meta_key Any meta_key value
*/
export function UserMeta({ id, meta_key }) {

    const [userData, setUserData] = useState({ id: 1 });

    useEffect(() => {
        // Use apiFetch to retrieve a single user by <id>
        async function getUser() {
            try {
                let response = await wp.apiFetch({ path: '/wp/v2/users/' + id });
                setUserData(response);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error.message);
            }
        }
        getUser();

    }, [id]);

    return (
        <span>{userData?.[meta_key] ?? 'empty..'}</span>
    );
}
```